# Xamarin Forms, reseting a variable at midnight

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am doing my first App on Xamarin Forms for a University project and I would be glad if someone here could help me.

The idea of the app is to track the amount of water that the user drinks every day and at midnight some of the data should be reset.
It seems that there is a solution for Xamarin Android but I am on Xamarin Forms and also the Alarm Manager is a bit out of my league...
Do you have any suggestion?

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: if you are logging every time the user enters their data, you should be able to detect if the entry is the first one for that day.  You shouldn't need to rely on an external timer to reset the data.

Comment: Could you maybe explain more about this? how does it detect that for example, the user did his first entry on the picker today?

Comment: I assume that you're storing these values in a db?  Then it's trivial to check if any existing entries exist for todays date.  Alternately, you could just save a single timestamp each time an entry is saved, then you can compare the current timestamp against the saved timestamp to determine if they are the same date.

Comment: Actually, it depends a lot on how exactly are you storing your data if you ask me, once you enlighten us a little on how you are doing that what you need to do is quite easy.

Comment: because it's the first ever project with Xamarin and a very easy one also , I am using application properties to store everything (I would be glad to hear other suggestions).

Comment: You can use Sqlite to create an actual local database or you could use JSON file write your data there and save it. It depends on what data you are using, but i would recommend SQLite. Application properties are good, but they only should be used for small data.

Comment: Ok, let´s say I will use SQLite, how it would be possible for me to remove the data at midnight?

Comment: I would like recommend you to store your data in a sever side, because users can change the time of their phone locally. It will cause some problem when you check if it is midnight right now.